# How to use FileZilla to connect with indirect remote server?

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, filezilla

I need to use FileZilla to connect with a server `10.12.23.4` which belongs to our school. However, I am now not in school, so if to connect with that server, I need to use my personal account to first connect with `username@**.edu`, then use that to connect with  `10.12.23.4`.

Now I hope to use FileZilla to connect with that server, so how to set the configuration so that can connect with it?

```
personal account--> username@**.edu--> 10.12.23.4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FileZilla has no native support for SSH tunelling (aka jump hosts/port forwarding).

You can setup an SSH tunnel using PuTTY from the intermediate server to the target server and connect with FileZilla to the tunnel.

See, details on [port forwarding in PuTTY](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-port-forwarding).

Or see a specific [guide for setting up port forwarding to tunnel file transfer client](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel#tunnel_putty) (WinSCP particularly, though you can apply it to FileZilla easily).

Actually, WinSCP SFTP client has a (single step) tunneling functionality built in. So, with WinSCP, it is very easy to do what you ask for. See the [*Tunnel* page](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_tunnel) of its Advanced Site Settings dialog.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Yeah, it works well. Thank you so much for your help.