# Configuring an SSH tunnel with FileZilla

Tags: windows, sftp, filezilla, ssh-tunnel

Is there any way to configure FileZilla on Microsoft Windows so that it connects to an SFTP server through some SSH tunnel?

E.g., with WinSCP, I can do the following:

[image]

I don't want to have to [launch the SSH tunnel another program such as PuTTY](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel#tunnel_putty) or running e.g.  `ssh -D 443 -v -N -L 443:my_server.org:22 franck50@my_server.org` then

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, FileZilla does not have the "Tunnel" feature of WinSCP.

But you can use an external tunnel: [How to use FileZilla to connect with indirect remote server?](https://superuser.com/q/1159768/213663)

Answer (score 1):

As Martin Prikryl, FileZilla doesn't support tunneling using a proxy server.

A feature request on this topic got closed: 
 [#4806 closed Feature request (rejected)
 - Add FTP over SSH (tunneling using a proxy server)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170209015224/https://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/4806)

Answer (score 1):

in short when using jumpserver

setup a local SOCKS 5 connection to the jumpserver using

```
ssh -D <availableport> -q -C -N user@jumpserver
```

then use the that in your filezilla settings

[FileZilla_settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb9xk.png)

compliments to: 
[reference-blog](https://ma.ttias.be/socks-proxy-linux-ssh-bypass-content-filters/)

Answer (score 0):

**How to create a SSH tunnel to encrypt a plain (insecure) ftp connection using FileZilla client & PuTTY**

**Summary:**

1. Filezilla FTP Client/Your local PC **<~~ [Conn. 1] ~~>** SSH server **<~~ [Conn. 2] ~~>** FTP server
   Connection 1 is encrypted using the SSH protocol.
   **Caution: Connection 2 is not encrypted.**
2. Configure FileZilla to use your local PC as a (generic proxy) SOCKS 5 server.
3. Configure PuTTY to create a SSH tunnel between your local PC and a SSH server using DYNAMIC port forwarding. In this mode, PuTTY acts as a proxy server.

The SSH server is a remote host that runs a SSH service (typically a Linux/Unix/BSD host). You must have an account to login to this host.

**Configuration Procedure:**

1. PuTTY configuration (for release 0.67 or similar):

   - Select "Category/Session"
     Host Name: SSH Server IP number or name
     Port: SSH server port number (22 by default)
     Connection type: SSH
   - Select "Category/Connection/SSH/Tunnels"
     Source Port: XXXX (5000 for instance, or any other unused high number)
     Destination: (leave it empty)
     Dynamic, Auto
2. FileZilla configuration (for version 3.46.3 or similar):

   - Select "Edit/Settings/Connection/Generic proxy"
     Type of generic proxy: SOCKS 5
     Proxy host: localhost
     Proxy port: XXXX (the SSH tunnel source port number, see PuTTY configuration above)
3. First **execute PuTTY** to create the desired SSH tunnel (you will be asked to provide username/password to login to the SSH server). Then **execute Filezilla client** using:

   - Protocol: FTP - File Transfer Protocol
     Host: FTP server IP number or name
     Port: (leave it empty, 21 by default)
     Encryption: Only use plain FTP (insecure)

**Possible uses:** your PC is on your home network, the SSH and FTP servers are behind your company's router/firewall, and:

1. you cannot access the ftp server directly (external connections to the ftp server are blocked for security reasons), or
2. you can access the ftp server directly but **you don't want to send your data (username/password/files) without encryption over the internet**.

See also:
https://documentation.help/PuTTY/using-port-forwarding.html
https://blog.devolutions.net/2017/4/how-to-configure-an-ssh-tunnel-on-putty
http://www.securebinary.co.za/ssh-port-tunneling-using-putty/

To save/load PuTTY configurations see:
https://documentation.help/PuTTY/config-saving.html