# FileZilla: connect from macOS via gateway to target

Tags: macos, ssh, sftp, filezilla

The OS of my local computer is MacOS (Catalina) and I want to transfer files to and from a remote server using FileZilla. I have to connect to a computer which sits in a protected subnet, so it's only reachable via a gateway.

I can establish a connection to the gateway computer via SSH with userID1 and password1, and from there I can connect to the desired computer with userID2 and password2:

```
Local computer (macOS)
   |
   | ssh user1@gateway.public.com 
   | 
   V
Gateway (Ubuntu)
   |
   | ssh user2@target.protected.machine 
   | 
   V
Target (Ubuntu)
```

I also can create both connections in one command:

```
ssh -t user1@gateway.public.com ssh user2@target.protected.machine
```

This works fine, but how can I use FileZilla to copy or move files between the local computer (macOS) and the target (Ubuntu)?

I've found some similar questions, but none of them answers my question:

- [How to use FileZilla to connect with indirect remote server?](https://superuser.com/q/1159768/175792)
  Local OS is Windows, the tools are putty and WinSCP
- [Configuring an SSH tunnel with FileZilla](https://superuser.com/q/1172990/175792)
  Again: Local OS is Windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the same what the other questions do on Windows even on MacOS.

Just use OpenSSH `ssh` instead of PuTTY. The `ssh` takes similar parameters as PuTTY.

So you can do something like this:

```
ssh -L 3111:target.protected.machine:22 user1@gateway.public.com
```

And then use FileZilla to connect to `localhost:3111` using credentials for `target.protected.machine`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you!