# configure file zilla proxy connection

Tags: proxy, filezilla

Let say Home -> server1(x,x,x,x) -> server(2)(192.168.0.1)

My company only allow to connect to server1 so I need to internally connect to server(2) with server(1).
so how can I set up the filezilla's proxy setting to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you talking about an SSH tunnel/port forwarding?

Comment: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ssh-proxy-bastion-proxyjump

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use FileZilla to connect with indirect remote server?](https://superuser.com/questions/1159768/how-to-use-filezilla-to-connect-with-indirect-remote-server)